# Test Failure is not captured after execution, shows Total test run: 0, Failures: 0, Skip: 0. when test is passed count is reflecting in Total & Pass

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a Selenium TestNG framework. Listeners are implemented. When my tests fail, at the end of log that is printed in console(By default of TestNG behavior), test failure is not being captured.

Says:

---

My Test Suite

Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

---

But I've executed 1 Test, which is failed due to ElementNotVisible or NoSuchElement. Where as, when Test is passed, the result shows
Total tests run: 1, Pass: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

What could be the reson for this. I've debugged my Listener when getting error, It goes to onTestFailure with runtime status mentioned as Fail. Later then, it end showing no failures.

TestNG execution & failure captured in the end result log

Comment: Please share code of your listeners, a concise example of your framework and how are you triggering your tests

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.